# Sum of infinite series, Are both of these series equal? 1/2+1/3+1/4...

Tags: sequences-and-series, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta, zeta-functions

from an old Numberphile video they explain that the sum of all natural numbers is equal to -1/12, 1+2+3+4+5+...= -1/12. Obviously it diverges, but the -1/12 is meant to be a meaningful representation of that infinite series.

In the extra footage for that video they also say that the -1/12 can be derived in a lot of ways including through the Reimann Zeta function.

When I was looking at the Reimann Zeta function it looked like they are summing 1 + 1/2 + 1/3 + 1/4 + 1/5..... Additionally, I also know that this harmonic series also diverges.

My question is, does 1 + 1/2 + 1/3 + 1/4 + 1/5..... also equal to -1/12 in the same way that the sum of all natural numbers does?

Please let me know.

Thank you.

Comment: First and for all, $1+2+3+\ldots\neq -\frac{1}{12}$, the equality you wrote is nonsense !(and with this logic you could assign any value you want to $1+2+3+\ldots$). However, what is true is that $\zeta(-1)=-\frac{1}{12}$ (which is not equal to $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{n^{-1}}$ !). The harmonic series would correspond to $\zeta(1)$ in your logic which does not exist as $\zeta$ is defined on the whole complex plane except at $1$.

Comment: I guess that you could say that "1 + 1/2 + 1/3 + 1/4 + 1/5..... also equal to -1/12 in the same way that" that the moon is made of green cheese.

Comment: @Tuvasbien $\zeta(s)$ has a Cauchy principal value at $s=1$, so it is still possible to extend this "nonsense" to harmonic series :D

Comment: Way too many videos busting that numberphile video by now, my recommendation is for the one by Mathologer- https://youtu.be/YuIIjLr6vUA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sum over all natural numbers actually diverges. What is true is that the Riemann zeta function $\zeta(s)$, which is defined by

$$
\zeta(s)=\sum_{n\ge1}{1\over n^s}
$$

for $\Re(s)>1$, can be extended to $\mathbb C\setminus\{1\}$ via analytic continuation. The $-\frac1{12}$ is just what you get when plugging $s=-1$ into the extended Riemann zeta function.

Since the harmonic series diverges at $s=1$, it is impossible to assign $-{1\over12}$ as in the case of natural numbers.

Although $\zeta(s)$ diverges at $s=1$, it is still possible to find its Cauchy principle value at $s=1$, thus allowing us to still assign something for the divergent harmonic series. For convenience, we directly quote some classical results from analytic number theory:

> **Lemma 1:** Let $a_n$ be a complex sequence, and
> $$A(x)=\sum_{n\le x}a_n.$$
> Then we have
> $$\sum_{n\ge1}{a_n\over n^s}=s\int_0^\infty A(e^t)e^{-st}\mathrm dt.$$
> **Lemma 2:** For $x\ge1$, we have
> $$H(x)=\sum_{n\le x}\frac1n=\log x+\gamma+O\left(\frac1x\right)$$,
> where $\gamma$ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant.

By lemma 1, we get

$$
\zeta(1+\delta)=\sum_{n\ge1}{1\over n^\delta}\cdot\frac1n=\delta\int_0^\infty H(e^t)e^{-\delta t}\mathrm dx
$$

Now, plug in lemma 2, we see that when $\Re(\delta)>0$,

\begin{align}
\zeta(1+\delta)
&=\delta\int_0^\infty(t+\gamma)e^{-\delta t}\mathrm dt+O\left(\delta\int_0^\infty e^{-(\delta+1)t}\mathrm dt\right) \\
&=\delta\int_0^\infty te^{-\delta t}\mathrm dt+\gamma+O(\delta).
\end{align}

Although the remaining integral converges only for $\Re(\delta)>0$, we can perform analytic continuation via Laplace transform. As a consequence, we obtain an expansion for $\zeta(1+\delta)$ valid for $|\delta|<1$:

$$
\zeta(1+\delta)=\frac1\delta+\gamma+O(\delta)
$$

This suggests that the Cauchy principal value of $\zeta(s)$ at $s=1$ is exactly $\gamma$:

$$
\lim_{\delta\to0}{\zeta(1+\delta)+\zeta(1-\delta)\over2}=\gamma
$$

Therefore, you can informally assign $\gamma$ to be the "sum" of reciprocals of positive integers.